# Unexpectedly changed permissions

Tags: c#, sql, permissions, connection, odbc

While trying to debug my site, I suddenly started getting this error:

```
ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Access denied for user 'admin'@'XXXXXXXX' (using password: YES)
```

and it pointed to these lines of code:

```
Line 37:         using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
Line 38:         {
Line 39:             con.Open();
```

I finally fixed the problem by changing this code:

```
private const string ConnStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};"
    + "Server=xxxx.xxx;Database=xxxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxXXxx;option=3";
```

from uid=admin to uid=root.
I'm sure it's bad coding practice to list root, but it's all I can do to get it to work.

Now the issue.  Suddenly a lot of my pages have this problem.  Last week they were working fine.  Now they won't work unless I change 'admin' to 'root'.  I've looked all around, but I think I've created my own unique brand of stupidity.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Someone has done a number on your permissions.  Did you install a new version of MySQL?  Could someone else have done the changes without your knowledge?  Are you in charge of the machine?  (It sounds like it since you have access to root account information.)  Is anyone else ever administering it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently install a Windows update? (Are you even running Windows? you don't say in your post). Or did someone just verify / repair permissions on your hard drive?

I've had programs that rely on permissions being set a certain way break after a Window update. Perhaps the update changed some .NET policy or something. It's possible your server was inadvertently taking advantage of incorrect permissions that were just corrected (by Windows Update or someone else).

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  I don't administer the site with anyone else and I am in charge of the machine.

I am running Windows and I haven't recently updated it to my knowledge.  I'll look into the time of the last update and see if it was before these problems.  
If that was the problem, then would the solution be to just change the permissions on the effected files?  Thanks again.

Comment: Well the solution would depend on what exactly the problem is, and I'm not pretending to know exactly what's going on. You could try randomly changing permissions, but that could take forever and sounds risky. If Windows Update (or another updater) did change the permissions, it was probably for a good reason. E.g. it may have plugged a security hole that you were inadvertently relying on, or maybe it just reset the permissions for some system files to their default settings. In any event, reinstalling MySQL might get things back to normal, although that too could be a wild goose chase.